# Thunderbird freezes after trying to delete all messages

Tags: thunderbird

I have Ubuntu 16.04.
Thunderbird freezes when I am trying to delete all messages at once.

I get warning unresponsive script
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: chrome://messenger/content/folderPane.js:2113

I don't have any extensions and am running latest Oracle java.

Comment: What is your mailbox size? Maybe Thunderbird is working to delete it and you just need to let it finish the service. Open Thunderbird by line-command and watch at terminal session what is it doing while it hangs.

Comment: 14K messages is the size